# Selenium server couldn't be started

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I updated R then I got the problem with rselenium

```
> system(paste0("kill $(lsof -i :4567 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')"))
sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
> rD <- rsDriver(chromever = Sys.getenv('CHROME_VERSION'), extraCapabilities = eCaps)
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  :
  Selenium server  couldn't be started
```

I tried to put `verbose = FALSE` into rsDriver but didn't work

```
> system(paste0("kill $(lsof -i :4567 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')"))
sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
> rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE, chromever = Sys.getenv('CHROME_VERSION'), extraCapabilities = eCaps)
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567 after 0 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(verbose = FALSE, chromever = Sys.getenv("CHROME_VERSION"),  :
  Could not determine server status.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and the solution the problem is found here: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/264#issuecomment-1344003384

The return value gives interesting info about chromedriver and chrome version too. If there is a mismatch it will fail too. But that is another topic.

```
library(wdman)
selenium(retcommand=T)
```